# Error in .Net "Operation illegal on linked parameter" in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have a Report which has 2 sub Reports in which the main Report parameter is linked to sub Report Parameter

When I am passing parameter to the main Report from C# Code, I am getting the following .Net error:

> Operation illegal on Linked Parameter

Can anyone please share me C# code?

```
        cryRpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/ProjectBillingGrid_Report.rpt"));
        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@PortfolioID", PortfolioID);
        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@ProjectID", 0);
        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@SubProjectID", 0);
        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@FYID", FYID);
        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@UserRole",1);
        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@EmployeeID",null);
        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@IsExcludeSubProject",false);
        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@SearchText",null);
        CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;               
        Session["ReportSource"] = cryRpt;
```

Comment: Show us your code so that we can understand problem better.

Comment: I have shared my code down

Comment: Pls add code in your question not as an answer.

Comment: I have added now sorry

Answer (score 1):

Make sure none of the parameters you are setting values for is a linked parameter.
Such parameters get their values from the main report and hence, cannot be set in code.

Comment: this is really an excellent, non-intuitive answer! I was quite surprised to see *all* of the report document parameters, including those from subreports, all globbed together in one crReportDocument.ParameterFields array list. The only readily apparent means of distinguishing subreport parameters from main report parameters is the subreport non-blank name (and perhaps non-matching value for main report name) and a null value for the prompt text, no?

Comment: Yes, the object model for Crystal is not designed/documented for ease of use... ;o)

Comment: no kidding! Here's perhaps a better way: 
    static bool crParameterInUse(String strParameterName) {
            if (crReportDocument.ParameterFields[strParameterName] == null || crReportDocument.ParameterFields[strParameterName].ToString() == "")
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return crReportDocument.ParameterFields[strParameterName].ParameterFieldUsage2 != ParameterFieldUsage2.NotInUse;
            }
        }